# Can I place an inductive range in an iron counter top?

Tags: appliances, stove, rebuild

I have a 1900 Bridge & Beech wood/gas cookstove that I'm refurbishing as electric/gas.  I'm considering placing an inductive range in the wood burner side of the cast iron top.  I can't find an answer to the question of how much (if any) energy escapes the inductive burner that would heat the surrounding cast iron cooktop.  Think of this as dropping an inductive range into a 1/4" thick steel countertop.

Can this be done?

If there is a minimum lateral distance required I'll find a non-ferrous plate to provide the necesary distance.

Comment: I'd be more concerned about the oven part overheating the electronics in the induction range...

Comment: I would contact the manufacturer. I would doubt that the coils are positioned close enough to the side to cause any problems if there were concerns there would be many cautions and easily found to prevent liability issues.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder ThreePhase Eel.  The oven is now electric and with Kaowool/air gap between the two sides. I still need to lock the flue open on the wood side to ensure a open pathway for updraft.

Comment: Ed, I'll post the mfg reply.  Minus the laughter.